# Simple trouble with awk and regex

Tags: regex, shell, awk, gawk

```
 echo xx y11y rrr | awk '{ if ($2 ~/y[1-5]{2}y/) print $3}'
```

Why I cannot get any output?

Thank you.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enable "interval expressions" in regular expression matching by specifying either the `--posix` or `--re-interval` option.

e.g.

```
echo xx y11y rrr | awk --re-interval '{ if ($2 ~ /y[1-5]{2}y/) print $3}
```

From the man page:

> --re-interval
>          Enable the use of interval expressions in regular expression matching (see Regular Expressions, below).  Interval expressions were
>   not traditionally  available  in
>          the  AWK  language.   The  POSIX standard added them, to make awk and egrep consistent with each other.  However, their use is
>   likely to break old AWK programs, so
>          gawk only provides them if they are requested with this option, or when --posix is specified.

Comment: So what should I do if donot use `{}`expression ?

Comment: instead of `[1-5]{2}`, you can use `[1-5][1-5]`.

Comment: nope, interval expressions such as `{2}` won't work unless you use the `--re-interval` or `--posix` flag.

Comment: `echo xx y11y rrr | awk --posix '{ if ($2 ~/y[1-5]\{2\}y/) print $3}'
` . It seems get no output.

Comment: you don't need to escape the curly braces.

Comment: To make it explicit: this applies to `gawk` (GNU `awk`) only. Quick update: since `gawk 4.0` you no longer need `--re-interval`.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine:

```
$ echo xx y11y rrr | awk '{ if ($2 ~/y[1-5]{2}y/) print $3}'
rrr
```

Was this what you wanted? I'm using GNU awk 4.0.0 in Cygwin on Windows XP.

Comment: eh, I still cannot get any output with your answer.

Comment: Seems like OS specific problem

Comment: The need to specify `--re-interval` in order to support interval expressions was dropped in gawk `4.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should force POSIX to use {} in awk

```
echo xx y11y rrr | awk -W posix '{ if ($2 ~/y[1-5]{2}y/) print $3}'
```

Comment: You try to use POSIX-regexp feature, but awk uses it's own regexp format. So u should force using POSIX format of regexp. Also look at dogbane's answer.